# Imagemagick bash convert jpgs in folder to pdf

Tags: bash, imagemagick

So I'm trying to make this work but I keep running into problems when making my script.

I have a folder with scanned jpgs which I then put into seperate folders if they belong together. Then I would like the script to create a sepereate pdf for each folder with all images in that folder.

This is my current script but it doesn't work. I also tried to make sure that the filename is equal to the oldest file in the folder (but that doesn't seem to work either)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for d in ./*/
do
cd "$d"
firstfile=$(ls -t | tail -n 1 | cut -d: -f1)
convert "*.jpg" "$firstfile.pdf"
done
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for d in $(pwd)/*/
do
   ...
```

At the moment, your paths are all relative to a directory you are no longer in after the first iteration.